# Directory Alias directory outside DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, virtualhost, apache2.4

I have to redirect a route from my main apache server to a directory outside DocumentRoot but always it returns a forbidden error.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /test on this server.

This is my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        Alias /test "/home/myuser/url.es/my-form/test"
        <Directory /home/myuser/url.es/my-form/test>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

To test that directory permissions is not the issue, I have granted 777:

```
drwxrwxrwx  6 root  root  4096 Feb  5 18:59 test
```

and inside:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root  root  4096 Feb  4 19:07 api
drwxrwxrwx 2 root  root  4096 Feb  4 19:07 assets
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root   585 Feb  4 19:07 crossdomain.xml
drwxrwxrwx 4 root  root  4096 Feb  4 19:07 img
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  1818 Feb  4 19:07 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    51 Feb  4 19:07 robots.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your error log and it will tell you exactly what the problem is. Likely one of the higher directories does not have search permission for the Apache user.

You don't seem to be granting permission for the DocumentRoot itself. Perhaps that's in your main config part.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I forgot to set `DirectoryIndex` so I couldn't access without specify the full file route.